# Why does a test that passes in Truffle fail when run against testrpc

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-deployment, testrpc, testing

Using [Truffle](http://truffleframework.com) and testing against both Truffle's own blockchain and against [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) yields different results.

I am trying to test that my deployed contract is setting its `owner` correctly (owner being set to `msg.sender` in the constructor)

```
contract Cocktail {
  address public owner;

  function Cocktail() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }
}
```

My Migration script is like

```
module.exports = (deployer, network, accounts) => {
  const superuser = accounts[0]
  console.log('Deploying to network', network, 'from', superuser)

  deployer.then(() => Cocktail.new({ from: superuser })).then((cocktail) => {
    console.log('Deployed Cocktail with address', cocktail.address)
  })
}
```

My test is like

```
const Cocktail = artifacts.require('./Cocktail.sol')

contract('Cocktail', (accounts) => {
  const superuser = accounts[0]

  it('is owned by superuser', () => Cocktail.deployed()
    .then(instance => instance.owner())
    .then((owner) => {
      assert.equal(owner, superuser, `Expected the owner to be '${superuser}'`)
    }))
})
```

If I just use Truffle's own blockchain and run `truffle develop` then `compile`, `migrate`, then `test` it's all good.

```
Contract: Cocktail
  ✓ is owned by superuser
```

If I fire up `testrpc` and run `truffle test` however it claims to migrate okay but the test fails:

```
Using network 'development'.

Deploying to network development from 0x9aa5b3cee03060172ec9968a49857c2a68341f67
Deployed Cocktail with address 0x2294c2ef0db6994cf0c5a777e10e5be5e7aab69b

  Contract: Cocktail
    1) is owned by superuser
    > No events were emitted

  0 passing (86ms)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: Cocktail is owned by superuser:
     Error: Cocktail has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This deploy script worked for both testrpc and internal blockchain

```
const Cocktail = artifacts.require("./Cocktail.sol");

module.exports = (deployer, network, accounts) => {
  const superuser = accounts[0];
  console.log('Deploying to network', network, 'from', superuser);

  deployer.deploy(Cocktail, { from: superuser }).then(() => {
    console.log('Deployed Cocktail with address', Cocktail.address);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Slowly but surely I'm getting the hang of this stuff :-)